# custom java.util.logging properties file resulting in duplicate log files

Tags: logging, jenkins, java.util.logging, winstone

I'm running a stand-alone Jenkins server launched from the WAR file.  Jenkins advertises itself as using the java.util.logging framework for logging.  I launch it as follows:

```
java -Djava.util.logging.config.file=mycustomlogging.properties -jar jenkins.war > jenkins.log
```

mycustomlogging.properties contains the following:

```
handlers=java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level=WARNING
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.formatter=java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter
```

What I expected is for all logging to go into jenkins.log and for only WARNING messages and above to be logged.

The contents of jenkins.log are as expected, but I'm also seeing a file ~/java0.log created that contains XML-formatted log statements at INFO and above.

Why is java0.log being created when I only specify a ConsoleHandler (and no FileHandler) in mycustomlogging.properties?

Is my properties file being "merged" with the default system one, which (presumably) configures a FileHandler writing to ~/java0.log?  My expectation was that specifying a custom properties file would completely override the default system behavior.

Or is it likely the server code is written such that it ignore the system properties and just logs to ~/java0.log "no matter what"?

If it matters, I'm on OS X 10.10 using Java 7.

Answer (score 0):

> Why is java0.log being created when I only specify a ConsoleHandler (and no FileHandler) in mycustomlogging.properties?

It is possible your properties file was never found or the configuration was thrown out by code performing a LogManager.reset() or LogManager.readConfiguration(InputStream).

> Is my properties file being "merged" with the default system one, which (presumably) configures a FileHandler writing to ~/java0.log?

A merge is not possible with the default LogManager.  There has to be code that is directly creating and adding the FileHandler.

> Or is it likely the server code is written such that it ignore the system properties and just logs to ~/java0.log "no matter what"?

Yes.  LogManager.reset will throw out your configuration.

Try to configure a [Groovy Hook Script](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Groovy+Hook+Script) to call LogManager.reset() and then install your ConsoleHandler.  This is described in the [Jenkins logging wiki](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Logging).